# CakePHP get associations of assotiations

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I have an Offers table that belongsTo Products table. The Products table belongsTo Markups table (with foreign key: markup_id).

Now, when I try this code:

```
$offersObject = $this->paginate($this->Offers->find('all')
                ->contain('Products');
```

I get results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => App\Model\Entity\Offer Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [store_id] => 1
            [product_id] => 1
            [price] => 150
            [new_price] => 0
            [status] => 1
            [twid] => 70261
            [magkod] => MAG
            [product] => App\Model\Entity\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => BOSCH S3 41Ah 360A S3001
                    [markup_id] => 3
                    [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                        (
                            [time] => 2018-01-08T14:30:38+00:00
                            [timezone] => UTC
                            [fixedNowTime] => 
                        )

                    [modified] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                        (
                            [time] => 2018-01-08T14:30:38+00:00
                            [timezone] => UTC
                            [fixedNowTime] => 
                        )


                    [[repository]] => Products
                )
        )
```

The problem is I literally get markup_id and what I need is the associated row from Products table.

From my OffersTable.php:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

ProductsTable.php

```
    $this->hasMany('Offers');

    $this->belongsTo('Markups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'markup_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Please advise. Or ask for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load nested associations using nested arrays:

```
$offersObject = $this->paginate($this->Offers->find('all')
                ->contain([
                    'Products' => [
                        'Markups'
                    ]
                ]);
```

Alternatively, you can express nested associations using the dot notation:

```
$offersObject = $this->paginate($this->Offers->find('all')
                    ->contain([
                        'Products.Markups'
                    ]);
```

[Eager Loading Associations Via Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)

Comment: Oh my God you just resolved more of my problems than you could imagine. Thank you kind sir!